# Remove carriage return from string

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I would like to insert the following into a string

```
<p>some text here</p>
<p>some text here</p>
<p>some text here</p>
```

I want it to go into a string as follows

```
<p>some text here</p><p>some text here</p><p>some text here</p>
```

i.e. without the carriage returns.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Since you're using VB.NET, you'll need the following code:

```
Dim newString As String = origString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
```

You could use escape characters (`\r` and `\n`) in C#, but these won't work in VB.NET. You have to use the equivalent constants (`vbCr` and `vbLf`) instead.

Comment: I didn't notice the VB.NET tag,  but as that is in there +1.

Comment: Good, but how about tabs. how one can remove tabs in the string?

Answer (score 13):

How about:

```
string s = orig.Replace("\n","").Replace("\r","");
```

which should handle the common line-endings.

Alternatively, if you have that string hard-coded or are assembling it at runtime - just don't add the newlines in the first place.

Comment: Basically, I am using the ckeditor which inserts carriage returns in the html it generates.  This is causing me problems later on for various reasons, and I don't know if I can change a setting in ckeditor to stop generating the carriage returns.  Also, it's probably safer to remove the carriage returns at the serverside stage right?

Comment: it's working.  
.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove spaces at the beginning/end of a line too(common when shortening html) you can try:

```
string.Join("",input.Split('\n','\r').Select(s=>s.Trim()))
```

Else use the simple `Replace` Marc suggested.

Comment: As an observation, this will work but involves 2 arrays and 2x *n* intermediate strings; but they should all be eligible for gen-0 collection, so still pretty cheap

Comment: Good point, I may eventually need to remove the spaces too.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This is the best way (I think) to remove hard \n and \r characters in a string.

Answer (score 4):

In VB.NET there's a [vbCrLf constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for linebreaks:

```
Dim s As String = "your string".Replace(vbCrLf, "")
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It won't work with the example given. I suspect that's because `vbCrLf` is actually defined as `vbCr + vbLf`, which isn't present in the string, but I'm not sure. Splitting them up is the only solution that will remove the line returns from the string; see my answer for a sample.

Comment: For completeness: For "the normal" dotnet framework there is Environment.Newline that _might_ be CRLF. Also as @CodyGray said: it is 2 chars.

Comment: This works for for removing line breaks in labels for Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Assign your string to a variable and then replace the line break and carriage return characters with nothing, like this:

```
 myString = myString.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It won't work with the example given. I suspect that's because `vbCrLf` is actually defined as `vbCr + vbLf`, which isn't present in the string, but I'm not sure. Splitting them up is the only solution that will remove the line returns from the string; see my answer for a sample.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
string res = string.Join("", sample.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
```

Environment.NewLine should make it independent of platform.

#### Recommended Read:

[Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) Property

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Regex?

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "\r\n", String.Empty)
```

If you just want to remove the new line at the very end use this

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "\r\n$", String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

For VB.net

vbcrlf = environment.newline...

Dim MyString As String = "This is a Test" & Environment.NewLine & " This is the second line!"

```
Dim MyNewString As String = MyString.Replace(Environment.NewLine,String.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft helped me on this one. I have a TextBox that I enter info into, when I hit Enter it transfers that info to another TextBox. The first TextBox has a CrLf which interfered with it's look. With this e.Handled, no CrLf. Hope it helps. I failed to say, VB.NET and WinForms.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

```
Private nonNumberEntered As Boolean = False
Private Sub TxtBxGetString_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TxtBxGetString.KeyPress

    TxtBxReversed.Text = ""

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        If nonNumberEntered = False Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
        str = TxtBxGetString.Text
        TxtBxReversed.Text = str
        TxtBxLength.Text = Len(str)
        TxtBxLength.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue in my code today and tried which worked like a charm.

```
.Replace("\r\n")
```