# Convert xml to pure string

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to serialize the class object to string. But it is giving output in the form of xml from the below code.

```
Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(response.GetType)
Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()
x.Serialize(sw, response)
Return sw.ToString
```

**Current Output**

```
<Employees>
<Employee>John</Employee>
<Employee>Peter</Employee>
</Employees>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<Employees><Employee>John</Employee><Employee>Peter</Employee></Employees>
```

Comment: So...you want all your output XML on 1 line? Why do you need that?

Comment: I need to write to log file in single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert the response text into an XML object, keep it as a string.

From there [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906279/remove-carriage-return-from-string) post should be enlightening.  Once that's all said and done and stored in a variable, you can do all the XML serializing your heart desires.

Comment: The OP is not parsing the XML into a document object.  The example code serializes directly to an XML string and then returns it as a string.  Doing a simple replace on the string would not remove white space added for XML indentation.

Comment: I guess I should specify that I'm a Javascript guy first and foremost.  I assumed that response was coming through as a string and that x.Serialize was parsing it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use an `XmlTextWriter` so that you can specify how you want the XML output formatted.  For instance:

```
Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(response.GetType)
Using sw As New IO.StringWriter()
  Using xw As New XmlTextWriter(sw)
    xw.Formatting = Formatting.None
    x.Serialize(xw, response)
    Return sw.ToString
  End Using
End Using
```