# how i can convert xml to String Value

Tags: vb.net

i have this xml but i need to convert to String Value

```
  <CheckList>
            <CheckListItem>
                <CheckListItemID>1532</CheckListItemID>
                <Notes>Note1</Notes>
                <Termination_ID>1532</Termination_ID>
                <Titel>Access Card</Titel>
            </CheckListItem>

            <CheckListItem>
                <CheckListItemID>1533</CheckListItemID>
                <Notes>note2</Notes>
                <Termination_ID>1532</Termination_ID>
                <Titel>Badge</Titel>
            </CheckListItem>

            <CheckListItem>
                <CheckListItemID>1531</CheckListItemID>
                <Notes>note3</Notes>
                <Termination_ID>1532</Termination_ID>
                <Titel>Laptop</Titel>
            </CheckListItem>
        </CheckList>
```

i Need to convert this Xml to String

I want these outputs

```
Access Card : Note1 , Badge : Note2 , Laptop : note3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert xml to pure string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867506/convert-xml-to-pure-string)

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath. You may have to import system.xml and system.xml.xpath into your page

```
    Dim myxml As String = "<CheckList><CheckListItem><CheckListItemID>1532</CheckListItemID><Notes>Note1</Notes><Termination_ID>1532</Termination_ID><Titel>AccessCard</Titel></CheckListItem><CheckListItem><CheckListItemID>1533</CheckListItemID><Notes>note2</Notes><Termination_ID>1532</Termination_ID><Titel>Badge</Titel></CheckListItem><CheckListItem><CheckListItemID>1531</CheckListItemID><Notes>note3</Notes><Termination_ID>1532</Termination_ID><Titel>Laptop</Titel></CheckListItem></CheckList>"
    Dim xp As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(New StringReader(myxml.ToString))
    Dim xn As XPathNavigator = xp.CreateNavigator
    Dim xi As XPathNodeIterator = xn.Select("//CheckList/CheckListItem")
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Do While xi.MoveNext
        sb.Append(xi.Current.SelectSingleNode("Titel").InnerXml & " : " & xi.Current.SelectSingleNode("Notes").InnerXml & " , ")
    Loop
    sb.Length = sb.Length - 3
    Response.Write(sb.ToString.TrimEnd(" , "))
```

this will output

AccessCard : Note1 , Badge : note2 , Laptop : note3

Comment: who i can check Node("Notes") is null