# How delete "vbLf&" in vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

When i passing `<td>` row to controller, i receive that string:

```
vbLf &"      364091670" & vbLf &"
```

Instead of just string variable: 364091670

Look the pic:
[image]

that my function:

```
function postCardNumber(elm) {


            var CardNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html();
            $.post("/CreditCard/ShowImage", { cardNumber: CardNumber }, function (response) {

                alert(response);

            });

            }
```

The CardNumber var is not correct.

I need to pass the right string to mongodb, but cant. Thx.

Comment: `vbLf` represents a line field. How are you rendering the html for that `<td>` element?

Comment: <td class="card-number">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.CreditCardInternalIdentifier)
                            </td>

Comment: It looks like the value of your `CreditCardInternalIdentifier` property has line feed characters. You should just remove them before passing the model to the view

Comment: How to remove that carriage?

Comment: Refer [these answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906279/remove-carriage-return-from-string) for examples (but its not clear why the value of your property has the line feeds in the first place)

Comment: Saw it, didnt help me :(