# Concatenate lines into one string

Tags: vb.net

I need to split and edit text from string to a certain formula.

The text String is:

```
1
2
3
4
5

1
2
3
4
5

1
2
3
4
5

1
2
3
4
5

1
2
3
4
5
```

And I need it to be:

```
1;2;3;4;5
<br>
1;2;3;4;5
<br>
1;2;3;4;5
<br>
1;2;3;4;5
<br>
1;2;3;4;5
<br>
1;2;3;4;5
<br>
```

---

In 1 string i have like 50 of those I need it to be lines of that formula.

Ive tried to use split by new lines and adding chars to every word and then split by char but it doesnt helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove carriage return from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906279/remove-carriage-return-from-string)

Comment: If you showed us the code you have tried, we could help you by letting you know where the code needed some changes. As it is, it looks like a "gimme teh codez" question, which would be below the standard expected on this site ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the line breaks are given as a CR/LF sequence

```vb
Dim result = input.Replace(vbCrLf, ";")
```

or

```vb
Dim result = input.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ";")
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pB08ay

---

Your updated more complex input string can be processed like this

```cs
Dim result = input.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ";").
                   Replace(";;", Environment.NewLine & "<br>" & Environment.NewLine)
```

We begin as before. This produces a string looking like `1;2;3;4;5;;1;2;3;4;5;;1;2;3;4;5;;1;2;3;4;5;;1;2;3;4;5`.
Then we replace the double semicolon by the `<br>` embedded between two line breaks.

Comment: It is working when there is only 1 group of numbers..

Comment: It is working when there is only 1 group of number. I have like 50 those groups every 5 lines in 1 string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function below:

```
Private Function FormatString(ByVal InputString As String) As String
    InputString = InputString.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
    For i = 0 To InputString.Length - 1
        InputString = InputString.Insert(i + i, ";")
    Next
    InputString = InputString.Remove(0, 1)

    Return InputString
End Function
```